# 3 Table SQL Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have trouble grasping joins between more that two tables and it's syntax.

I need to grab parent Staff Name, Vendor Name, Zone ordered by zone. Unsure if this is enough data.

TABLES

vendor
vendor_staff
type_zone

This is my weirdest attempt ever and I believe I'm very far away. I know that I'm missing possible enclosed parenthesis clauses.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT 
vendor.name AS Vendor, vendor_staff.vendorstaff AS Staff,type_zone.type AS Region
FROM dbo.vendor inner join dbo.type_zone
ON fkType_zoneID = pkType_ZoneID 
WHERE dbo.vendor.active = 1 and vendor_staff.fkVendorID = vendor.PkVendorID
ORDER BY type_zone.type, name
```

**The three tables could be join using:**

```
vendor.pkvendorID = vendor_staff.fkVendorID
type_zone.pkType_ZoneID = vendor.fkType_zoneID
```

The result should return per row Staff - > Vendor -> Zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Vendor = v.name,
    Staff = vs.vendorstaff,
    Region = t.[type]
FROM
    dbo.vendor AS v
INNER JOIN
    dbo.vendor_staff AS vs
    ON v.pkvendorID = fkVendorID
INNER JOIN
    dbo.type_zone AS t
    ON v.fkType_zoneID = t.pkType_ZoneID
WHERE
    v.active = 1
ORDER BY
    t.type,
    v.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Joins are INNER unless you specify `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `FULL`, optionally adding `OUTER`.

```
SELECT v.name        AS Vendor,
       s.vendorstaff AS Staff,
       t.type        AS Region
  FROM dbo.vendor       AS v
  JOIN dbo.vendor_staff AS s ON v.pkvendorID    = s.fkVendorID
  JOIN dbo.type_zone    AS t ON v.fkType_zoneID = t.pkType_ZoneID 
 WHERE v.active = 1
 ORDER BY t.type, name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
vendor.name AS Vendor, 
vendor_staff.vendorstaff AS Staff,
type_zone.type AS Region
FROM 
dbo.vendor 
inner join dbo.type_zone ON fkType_zoneID = pkType_ZoneID
inner join dbo.vendor_staff on fkVendorID = PkVendorID
WHERE dbo.vendor.active = 1
ORDER BY 
type_zone.type, 
name
```

Answer (score 0):

You used a hybrid of ANSI and Traditional joins.

You can can do it completely through JOINs, like this:

```
SELECT
   v.name as Vendor,
   s.vendorstaff as Staff,
   t.type_zone as Region
FROM
   vendor v 

   INNER JOIN type_zone t 
   ON v.fkType_zoneID = t.pkTpe_ZoneID

   INNER JOIN vendorstaff s 
   ON v.pkVendorID = s.fkVendorID
WHERE
   v.active = 1
ORDER BY
   t.type_zone,
   v.name
```

Or you can do it completely without joins (traditionally), like this

```
SELECT
   v.name as Vendor,
   s.vendorstaff as Staff,
   t.type_zone as Region
FROM
   vendor v,
   type_zone t,
   vendorstaff s 
WHERE
       v.fkType_zoneID = t.pkTpe_ZoneID
   AND v.pkVendorID = s.fkVendorID
   AND v.active = 1
ORDER BY
   t.type_zone,
   v.name
```